# Saving an array of Integers using UserDefaults

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to save an array of Integers to UserDefaults. I'm having an error when I try to run the code. I'm working in Swift Playgrounds.

```
if let temp = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedSugarArray") as? [Int] {
        savedSugarArray = temp
    }
```

Im getting an error on the last line of my playground, which is

```
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

The error is EXC_Bad_Instruction

Thanks

Comment: That 1st line is bad. The `if` statement is just what you want. What issue are you having with the `if let...`?

Comment: Ok so how should I declare my savedSugarArray. Just as an array of Integers? @rmaddy

Comment: What else would it be? What is it now? You need to clarify your question. You've posted two sets of code and stated there is an error. Clearly the 1st line of code will cause the error when there is no array saved yet. But the 2nd bit of code is fine. But you seem to indicate you have a problem with the 2nd bit of code. Clarify what your issue is.

Comment: Im just getting an error on the last line of code `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()`. It says EXC_BadInstruction. @rmaddy

Comment: What does that have to do with what you posted in your question. Please, if you want help, [edit] your question with relevant and clear details about your issue. Make it easy for people to help you. It shouldn't be a game of 20 questions just to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Ok sorry I edited my question. Thanks for the help. @rmaddy

Comment: I don't know if the above is all your code (I assume not), but your code would crash on the `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()` line if you don't have a `ViewController` class defined in your playground. Do you have the class defined? And if yes, do you know what you are doing with the `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()` line?

Comment: Yes, the PlaygroundPage line allows me to see a view when I run my code. I also have the ViewController class defined. I get an error at a different place on my iPad.`average = sum/savedSugarArray.count` All it says is There was an error when running your playground.